# Why does R not display and recognize all factor levels?

Tags: r, rstudio

When declaring a variable as factor, R does not recognize all levels.

For example, this code will result in a conflict(see pictures).

```
dataset$search_term_id <- factor(dataset$search_term_id, levels = unique(dataset$search_term_id),nmax = 100000)
```

There are only 3000 levels in the dataset. However, the code to declare all characters as factor levels, result in problems... This will lead to problems with further analysis, because some models recognize only 1 factor level.

[image: The problem]
[[image: However, here the number is factor level is displayed correctly][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmbne.png)

I have tried multiple ways, using `unique()` etc., however `R` does not display the number of factor levels correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please make a reproducible example of your issue.

Comment: I guess that this is just problem with the _View_ interface. The 2nd picture shows that `search_term_id` is a `factor` with `3237 levels`. I tested this behavior in my RStudio and it is the same - _View_ shows 1 level, `str` shows 393 levels.